# How to reshape a dataframe into percentage of categorical data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains longitudinal information (a long format).

```
mydata<-structure(list(record_id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c","c"),event = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label =c("e2", "e3", "e4"), class = "factor"), var1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"),var2 =structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), var3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),.Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class= c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I need to transform this data into a dataframe that summarize the percentage of "yes" counts of each variable (var1,var2,var3) according to the event (e2,e3,e4) to have something like this:

```
mydata_result<-structure(list(Event = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("e2", "e3", "e4"), class = "factor"), Variable =structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "factor"), percentage_of_yes = c(0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 0, 0.33, 0.66, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, we can convert to long format, group by our variable and event, and do the percentage count, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% 
  gather(var, val, -c(1:2)) %>% 
  group_by(event, var) %>% 
  summarise(new = sum(val == 'yes')/n())
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 3
> # Groups:   event [?]
>   event var     new
>   <fct> <chr> <dbl>
> 1 e2    var1  0.333
> 2 e2    var2  0.333
> 3 e2    var3  0.667
> 4 e3    var1  0    
> 5 e3    var2  0.333
> 6 e3    var3  0.667
> 7 e4    var1  0    
> 8 e4    var2  0    
> 9 e4    var3  0
> ```

Comment: Thank you Sotos, just the last question. In some of the variables (var1, var2) I have missings but when I run your code the % is computed taking into account the whole n (even with the number of NAs), I have tried to put na.rm=TRUE in the sum function but It did not work, any idea?

Comment: How about filtering them out before hand? For example before the `summarise()`, you can add a filter, i.e. `...%>%filter(!is.na(val)) %>% summarise()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(mydata), id.vars = c("record_id", "event"))[, 
 .(percentage_of_yes = round(mean(value == "yes"), 3)), 
        .(event, Variable = variable)]
#    event Variable percentage_of_yes
#1:    e2     var1             0.333
#2:    e3     var1             0.000
#3:    e4     var1             0.000
#4:    e2     var2             0.333
#5:    e3     var2             0.333
#6:    e4     var2             0.000
#7:    e2     var3             0.667
#8:    e3     var3             0.667
#9:    e4     var3             0.000
```